# What are JQuery rules for enclosing arguments in quotes? Why both $(document) and $('document') is OK, but only $(this) allowed?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery I can write `$(document)` and `$('document')` / `$("document")`, but only `$(this)` is allowed (I cannot enclose `this` in any quotes). Also, any selector shall be quoted: (`$("div")` is OK, while `$(div)` is not).

I cannot understand what exactly shall

- always be quoted
- can be quoted optionally
- never be quoted

For example, `this` and `document` both seem to be (special) keywords (not selectors) but having different rules for them is confusing. Also I guess that any jQuery Selector shall always be quoted.

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){  <!-- $('document') is also valid -->
     $('p').click(function(){
       $(this).hide();            <!-- $('this') is invalid -->
       $("div").hide();
     });     
   });    
  </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean `$('this')` is invalid? It would select a `<this></this>` element, no?

Comment: ^ that summarises the topic very well ;)

Comment: Yes $('this') selects <this> element (tag), you are right. So is $(this) is the only case when no quotes are OK in any $(something) construction - to differentiate between <this> tag and this as currently chosen element like in  $('p').click(function(){      $(this).hide(); });

Comment: It's the same for `$('document')` as well. That will search the DOM for a `<document>` tag and won't find the actual document (which is your intention). So I'm not sure why you believe it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery function (`$()`) can take several types of arguments, including (but not limited to):

1. a DOM element (object -- not string)
2. a selector (string)

You can use the first syntax when you have a variable/property that references a DOM element.

In the second syntax jQuery will apply the selector to *find* the matching DOM element(s). This means the string must follow the CSS syntax (with some jQuery extensions to it).

The two are quite different.

#### `$('document')` selects nothing

It is a misunderstanding that `$('document')` selects anything. It follows the second syntax, but 'document' is not a selector that returns anything, as `<document>` is not an element (unless you specifically added one).

You can see here that it selects nothing:

```js
console.log($("document").length); // 0
console.log($(document).length); // 1
// Now add a <document>:
var doc = document.createElement('document');
document.body.appendChild(doc);
// ... and it works
console.log($("document").length); // 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### jQuery's `.ready()` method

You mention that `$('document').ready()` works -- and this may be the deeper cause of your question -- but that is because the selector is irrelevant for `ready` to work. Quoted from [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the
>   DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $( handler )
> $( document ).ready( handler )
> $( "document" ).ready( handler )
> $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> $().ready( handler )
> ```

It does not matter what you select. Even `$('abcdef').ready` will work.

#### `this`

jQuery sets `this` to the relevant DOM element when calling the callback function in many of its methods. This makes `this` a candidate value to pass to `$` (the first syntax). `$(div)` will not work, because `div` is *not* a variable, unless you declared it:

```js
$("div").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text()); // "hello"
    // Does not work:
    console.log($(div).text()); // ""
    var div = this;
    // Now it works:
    console.log($(div).text()); // "hello"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example: `$(this).hide();`, `this` is a JavaScript variable representing the 'P' that was clicked, triggering the event.

JavaScript variables are never quoted.

DOM element selectors are always quoted (document and window are "special cases").

To refer to any elements on the DOM, you must surround it with quotations. For example:
If you have HTML that looks like this:

```
<button>Click my button</button>
```

Your jQuery may look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function({
   // listen for hover on the button
   $('button').mouseenter(function() { ... });  // 'button' is a selector for <button>, use quotations

   ...

   // assign the button to a variable and perform an action
   var buttonVar = 'button';  
   $(buttonVar).mouseenter(function(){ ... }); // buttonVar is a variable, do not use quotations

});
```

In the case of `$(this)`, `this` is a variable that represents the currently active element.  Personally, I use `$(this)` when cycling through a series of elements of the same type, or through the elements of an array.

For example, your HTML may look like this:

```
<p class="highlight">Highlight me</p>
<p class="nohighlight">Do not highlight me</p>
<p class="highlight">Highlight me</p>
```

your jQuery may look like this:

```
$('.highlight').each(function(){         // 'highlight' is a selector for class="highlight", use quotations
   $(this).css("background","yellow");   // this is a variable, do not use quotes
});
```